# Insert from multiple tables gives duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in `mysql` named `a` and `b`. Both of them have a unique column `id`. Now I want to create a table `abc` that has `id` as autoincrement column by inserting records from both the tables `a` and `b`.

```
Table a

1 sam
2 ram
3 tim


table b 

1 tom
2 sun
3 jim
```

Desired result

```
table abc

1 sam
2 ram
3 tim
4 tom
5 sun
6 jim
```

I have tried like below

```
insert into table abc select * from a
```

This statement runs succesfully

```
insert into table abc select * from b`
```

This statement fails saying duplicate entry for primary

How can I achieve my desired result

Comment: What are the column names?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel columns are `id` and `names`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in the `abc` table create its own values. Don't select and insert the `id` column from other tables.

```
insert into table abc(names) select names from a order by id;
insert into table abc(names) select names from b order by id;
```